# How to simulate a drag and drop function for Moo0 File Shredder?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, drag-and-drop

[Moo0 File Shredder](https://www.moo0.com/?top=https://www.moo0.com/software/FileShredder/) is a Windows utility that does use a drop box area and the drag-and-drop function to "select" files and folders to automatically erase them.

In order to make things faster I've added a SendTo shortcut to files and folders context menu, but it is not yet enough...

Is there a way in order to simulate a drag'n drop action through a batch file or a VBScript calling it from the context menu of files and folders?

That's a way to "send" a file or a folder directly to the program drop box area?

Thanks

[Program features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGxir.png)

Comment: maybe easier to get a [command line utility](https://www.google.de/search?q=+File+Shredder+command+line)

Comment: many thanks for your appreciated reply, but I love to use Moo0 File Shredder due to its uncommon features that maybe are hard to get in a different way. Just added a sshot describing app features to 1st post.